# How to sort <option> generated dynamically in <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

I have 4  fields that are generated based on the input of the previous one, like in a tree list. Example:

```
<select id="confederation">
    <option value="">Confederation</option>
    <option value="29521">Europe (UEFA)</option>
    <option value="38731">South America (CONMEBOL)</option>
    <option value="40934">Africa (CAF)</option>
    <option value="43099">North &amp; Central America (CONCACAF)</option>
    <option value="44624">Asia (AFC)</option>
    <option value="46617">Oceania (OFC)</option>
</select>
<select id="country">
    <option value="">Country</option>
</select>
<select id="team">
    <option value="">Team</option>
</select>
<select id="competition">
    <option value="">Competition</option>
</select>
```

As you can see, only the first list is populated initially. Once you select the "`confederation`", the "`country`" gets populated accordingly, then after choosing a "`country`", the "`team`" gets populated and so on.

What I would like to achieve is to sort this lists alphabetically; they are multi-language supported, so I cannot 'hard-code' a certain order.

I have the following script to properly sort the first list:

```
$("#confederation").append($("#confederation option:gt(0)").sort(function (a, b) {
            return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
        }));
```

How to modify it in order to accommodate all the lists and sort them properly?

Here is how the lists are populated using smarty:

```
{section name=foo start=0 loop=$tree_depth}
{assign var="index" value=$smarty.section.foo.index}
<select id="{$id}">
<option value="">[[{$levels_captions.$index}:raw]]</option>
    {*{defining parent of the curent selectbox}*}
    {if $index == 0}
        {assign var='parent' value=0}
    {else}
        {assign var='parentIndex' value=$index-1}
        {assign var='parent' value=$value.$parentIndex}
    {/if}
    {*{generating tree items based on parent}*}
    {foreach from=$tree_values.$parent item=tree_value}
        <option value="{$tree_value.sid|escape}"{if $value.$index == $tree_value.sid} selected="selected"{/if}>[[PhrasesInTemplates!{$tree_value.caption}]]</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```

I disagree that this question should be marked as duplicated. The solution proposed in the other thread applies in part to this question, but it cannot be implemented to this one. Or I'm missing something obvious, hence the question!

Comment: Just apply the sort function you already have to the elements as you append them?

Comment: How/where is the other option data stored?

Comment: @billyonecan - It does not work the way I tried at least. Also, the list is generated using smarty, I'll update it with more info about it.

Comment: @RachelGallen - 2 different problems in my POV but I'm using the same example.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {

    sortOptions($("#confederation"));

});

function sortOptions(selectElement) {
    var options = selectElement.find('option').get(); //get() returns an array of all option elements
    options.sort(optionsSort);
    /*Load the new array of sorted option elements into the select element, 
get the select element using get(0) so that we can access properties specific to HTMLSelectElement, 
eventually keep the first option selected(Without this, the last option is selected) */
    selectElement.html(options).get(0).selectedIndex = 0; 


}

function optionsSort(o1, o2) {
    if(o1.text == o2.text) return 0;
    return (o1.text > o2.text)? 1 : -1;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4NQtc/1/)

This way you can use `sortOptions(selectElementWrappedInjQuery)` when the other select elements are populated.

Comment: For some reason I can't make this work properly. Would you be kind to explain it better?

Comment: @Arkymedes I have added more verbose comments in the code. BTW sortOptions() requires passing in a jQuery object and not a raw DOM object. For e.g., to sort `country` you would use: `sortOptions($('#country'))`

Comment: Hello and I sincerely appreciate the time you are putting into this but for some reason it does not work.

I'm not savvy to all things programming but I do have a good notion about it. I just can't put this together.

What is happening right now is that the first list gets sorted (I have to skip the first element that I don't want sorted since it's the title), but when I choose anything from the #confederation list, the second list #country does not get sorted the moment it's populated.

I'm not sure how to trigger the script the moment the second list gets populated.

Again, thanks so much :)

Comment: I suppose`sortOptions` did work for `#confederation`. It should work for the other `select`s as well. After you're done populating the `#countries`, immediately use sortOptions($("#countries")); Same applies to `#team` and `#competition`